# KVO AVPlayer.status in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, key-value-observing

I need to observe **AVPlayer.status** change.

I have an **AVPlayer** instance and a **context** variable

```
private var lastPlayer : AVPlayer?
private var playerStatusContext = 0
```

After I've set up the **AVPlayer** instance I add an **observer** like so:

```
//  KVO status property
self.lastPlayer!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: [.new, .initial], context: &playerStatusContext)
```

Then I've overridden **observeValue** function like so:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)
{
    let status : AVPlayerStatus? = change?[.newKey] as? AVPlayerStatus
    if(status != nil && context == &playerStatusContext)
    {
        //  DO MY STUFF
    }
}
```

The problem is that **change** is either 0 key/value dictionary or some (whatever that means) and my local **status** constant is always **nil**, hense I can't do my stuff.

Maybe I am converting **change** to **AVPlayerStatus** wrongly? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Print `change` in the `observeValue` method. What do you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems like cast like this

```
let status : AVPlayerStatus? = change?[.newKey] as? AVPlayerStatus
```

does not work. The app crashed when tried checking change for nil and then force unwrap it. Using raw values helped:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)
{
    //  Check status
    if keyPath == "status" && context == &playerStatusContext && change != nil
    {
        let status = change![.newKey] as! Int
        //  Status is not unknown
        if(status != AVPlayerStatus.unknown.rawValue)
        {
            //  DO STUFF!!!
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure this is the best way however.

Comment: let status = AVPlayerStatus(rawValue: change![.newKey] as! Int)!

Comment: Apple's version: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem